# ASP.Net: Use a user selected value in my C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

In my `.cshtml` page I have this code:

```
@{
    Sabloane sabloane = new Sabloane(**2**, ex.TextNormal);
    var help= sabloane.GetSabloane();
    foreach (var elem in help) {
         <div class="aparitii"> @elem.text : @elem.aparitii </div>
    }
}
```

There, the "2" represents a number that needs to be inserted by the user, not hard coded by me. Below I have this:

```
 <select class="cifre" id="cifre">
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
 </select>
```

The `C#` code above is executed when I press a `button`. I want the value that the user chooses from the select to be there, not my "2". How can I do that?

Comment: This `Sabloane sabloane = new Sabloane(**2**, ex.TextNormal);` runs on the server. The selection occurs on the client. So are talking about on postback or something else?

Comment: C# code works before page rendering. The action you want could be done with javascript or one of it's frameworks

Comment: At the moment they do not interact. I need to make somehow for the c# code to re-execute when I press the button to trigger it. At the moment, that button just makes display:block the placeholder div which holds what  the code returns.

Comment: Put your select in a form give it a `name` attribute and pick that up in the postback action and then feed that to your c# code.

Comment: So the solution would be to make a new View in my controller and use post to get the value.